# Having multiple URL structure for wordpress blog

Tags: plugins, urls

I'm moving a blog from hubspot to wordpress and i'm facing an issue, I would like to have multiple structure URLs for the blog, we are a company and the goal is to keep separate news about company, carreer events etc
So basically the URL structure will look like.

```
   domainName.com/blog/en/news/%article%
   domainName.com/blog/en/events/%article%
   domaineName.com/blog/fr/evenenements/%article%
    domaineName.com/blog/fr/news/%article%
```

We are using WPML for multilanguage website. If you have any idea how i could achieve it, i would appreciate. I did look at the doc of WPML and some Q&A and did not find any answer. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Are those URLs for different content? Or for the same content? Are the pages identical? It's not clear. Note that WPML and 3rd party questions are off topic here, you won't find help for the WPML portion of your question here

Comment: Sure, so the URL have different content, and page are different too. We have for example a blog carreers (which contains all the positions available for US) and a blog Carriere (which contain all the positions available for France) and it's the same for our blogpost content, the news EN are different from FR news etc.